# wait / sleep until a remote file is unlocked in c

Tags: c, locking

On a sftp server i create a "lockfile.lock" if another application is manipulating data.
No in my c application i would like to check if the lockfile.lock exists and than "WAIT 5 SECONDS".

How do i wait 5 seconds in c without blasting the CPU to 100%?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows and linux there is a system call "sleep()". [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h>
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

DESCRIPTION
   sleep()  makes  the  calling  process  sleep  until  seconds seconds
   have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.
```

Comment: i always thought, sleep() is also loading the cpu very high. But i give it a try.

Comment: It does not use *any* CPU while sleeping.

Comment: It actually suspends the thread that calls it, so explicitly declaring to the OS "I'm having a break". The OS will move to a different thread to execute and come back to yours later. You can call Sleep(0) and then the OS will move to a different thread (probably).